# How can i refer to label inside listview .NET MAUI

Tags: maui

I have ListView with Label inside:

```
 <ListView BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           Margin="25" Grid.Row="1"
           x:Name="raspList" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding TheList}" 
           SelectionMode="None"
           Refreshing="updateRasp"
           RowHeight="55">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <ViewCell>
                 <Grid Padding="1">
                 <Label     HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Text="{Binding TheLine}"
                            TextColor="#424038"
                            FontSize="24"
                            FontFamily="Primary"
                            x:Name="lvstring"     <-------------
                            LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                 </Grid>
             </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

I need to  refer to lvstring from my MainPage.xaml.cs but i cannot since variable doesnt declared. TY!

Comment: You can’t reference elements inside of templates by name.  Use data binding instead

Comment: Yes, we usually use data binding to achieve this. What do you want to achieve?